# iOS Facebook SDK get profile cover image

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, profile

How can i get the cover of a profile with the FacebookSDK in iOS?

```
 [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/events?fields=cover"
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {

                          /* handle the result */
                          NSLog(@"%@", result);
                      }];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can also get facebook cover pic by simply calling

```
http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id or page_id}?fields=cover
```

Comment: This returns `{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}`